# Confirmation of radio button choice

Tags: javascript, webforms, confirm

I've been trying to create a confirm box in JavaScript for the form I'm working on so that the user has to confirm the radio button option that they chose. I've managed to get the validation working, but I cannot get the name of the radio button to show up in the confirm box (instead, it says "You have chosen unconfirmed, is this correct?" regardless of which option I pick). Here is the Javascript validation part of the code; where have I gone wrong?

```
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('choices');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
    checked = inputs[i].value;
    break;
  }

}

if(checked==null)
{
alert('Please choose an option.');
return false;
}

else{
return confirm('You have chosen '+ checked.value + ', is this correct?');
}
```

EDIT: Here is my HTML for the radio buttons, hope this helps

```
<tr>
        <td id="options">Options</td>
        <td id="gcse"><input type="radio" name="options" value="GCSE" /> GCSE</td>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="btec"><input type="radio" name="options" value="BTEC" /> BTEC</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="as"><input type="radio" name="options" value="AS" /> AS Level</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="alevel"><input type="radio" name="options" value="alevel" /> A2 Level</td> </tr>
```

Comment: Where are your options you are choosing from? Have you failed up update a value? 

Also, you set checked = input[i].value, but in your output string you say checked.value, when you should really just have to use checked.

Comment: just added the options' HTML, hope that helps! @sparkyShorts

Comment: Try changing checked.value to checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your script works almost. But you make one step too many.

You request `input.value.value` which will result in `undefined`.

If you change `checked = inputs[i].value;` to `checked = inputs[i]` your code will work fine.

> However if you select using `document.getElementsByName('choices');` the name of your radio elements must match `choices`.

Added a simple click handler to the radio buttons in this example here to show you the difference:

```js
function check()
{
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('choices');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
    checked = inputs[i];
    break;
  }

}

if(checked==null)
{
alert('Please choose an option.');
return false;
}

else{
return confirm('You have chosen '+ checked.value + ', is this correct?');
}
  }
```

```html
<input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="choices" value="value 1">Value 1 <br />
<input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="choices" value="value 2">Value 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Their is a minor mistake in your code just write this in your else condition

**return confirm('You have chosen '+ *checked*+ ', is this correct?');**

Just remove the .value from checked.value

this is bcoz you have already collected the value above and you were doing 
something like this...

checked.value == input[i].value.value

This is why you were not getting what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML it's hard to present the solution. But you could access the name of the input-tag by calling `checked.name`.

Comment: i've just added the HTML for the radio buttons, hope that helps?

Comment: @gulliver You are calling value two times, try to remove the second call to value when you return your string.